# Deleting a file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write the code below to delete a file:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
file.Delete(Path);
```

but I am getting the error that file.Delete(path) takes 1 argument please help me

Comment: Haha, 7 nearly identical answers in < 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an instance of FileInfo having a filename as an arguement. 
Method file.Delete() will remove the file which you passed through a constructor.
In fact, the argument of constructor must be an absolute path along with filename.

```
String filename=@"c:\xyz\aa.txt";
FileInfo file=new FileInfo(filename);
file.Delete();
```

Comment: Same answer with difference of 8 seconds :)

Answer (score 6):

The method Delete of FileInfo does not accept any parameter, so you need to write your code like this:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename); 
file.Delete();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your use of FileInfo.Delete takes no arguments.

You want something like:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename); 
file.Delete();
```

Comment: @Surya sasidhar: You know you can accept his answer if it resolve your problem. It is just the way StackOverflow works...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
                System.IO.File.SetAttributes(info.FullName,     
                                       System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal);
                System.IO.File.Delete(info.FullName);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be as below :

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
file.Delete();
```

The **[Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete.aspx)** method of FileInfo object does not take any arguments.